# Replace Paired Empty nodes in xml with Self Closing Nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xslt, ssis-2008

I have some xml, part of which looks something like this:

```
<BasicInfo>
  <Foo>80</Foo>
  <Bar>
  </Bar>
</BasicInfo>
```

I would like to replace all empty node open-and-close pairs (like `<Bar>` above) with single self-closing nodes, to give something like this:

```
<BasicInfo>
  <Foo>80</Foo>
  <Bar />
</BasicInfo>
```

I know that in xml, the two are equivalent and that the xslt will choose how it wants to output empty nodes and so on, but I have a lot of empty nodes and the expected file size difference in the two interpretations is large enough to be worth worrying about; I'd like the xml to be stored as efficiently as possible.

The xml above was created from SQL Server, then transformed with another XSLT that removes all the "xsi:nil" values and xmlns declarations that SQL Server 2008 left behind:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*[local-name(.)='noNamespaceSchemaLocation']" />
  <xsl:template xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" match="@xsi:nil" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is this stylesheet that leaves the open-and-close pairs behind - is there any way to force it to leave behind self closing nodes, or to make a new xslt to on its own produce this effect?

Sadly removing the nodes is not an option:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <!--Remove all the empty nodes-->
  <!--copy nodes-->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--match only those with no contents at all-->
  <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']" />
  <!--now check all those that have existing but empty children and don't return the children if they are empty-->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="descendant::text()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this is the closest I have got. I have found other people asking this question, but my poor knowledge of xslt means that I am having trouble altering the solutions given to my needs (it has taken a very long time to get the ones above sorted out!) . It seems that something along the lines of normalize-space is the way to go? I'd really appreciate some help!

*NB. The xml is produced by SQL Server 2008 R2, using `FOR XML PATH` and the XSLT scripts are stored in an xml column on the server; An XML task in SSIS 2008 with operand type XSLT applies the transform.*

Comment: Is the creation of this XML under your control?

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that I am using SQL Server to make it.

Comment: `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` should do it. Are you using `XSLCompiledTransform` to execute the transformation by any chance? You might need to pass in `XSLCompiledTransform.OutputSettings` to `XmlWriter.Create` for `XmlWriter` to use the output settings you define in the stylesheet.

Comment: I thought the same initially about `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`, but figured I must just be wrong. I do not know whether I am using XSLCompiledTransform or not... it's just an XML Task in SSIS, taking one variable as my xml file and another as the XSLT. Should I change to using a script task and try to do as you say?

Comment: Can you show a query that generates the XML in the first place? Chances are, it can be modified so that it will produce these pesky nodes already as self-closed.

Comment: I will see what I can do - there are several queries putting xml snippets into temp tables before joining the whole lot together, so it may not be possible to get a really good demonstration... Also, I am using `FOR XML PATH` with the `XSNIL` hint, so the empty nodes come out of SQL looking like `<Bar xsi:nil="true" />` - it is the first XSLT in the question that produces the open-and-close pairs at the empty nodes.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE #Demo
( Id  INT  IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL
 ,Value1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
 ,Value2 VARCHAR(30) NULL
);
INSERT #Demo(Value1,Value2)
VALUES('Bar',NULL);

   
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://tempuri.org/MySchema.xsd' AS xsd)
SELECT
  This.Id
 ,( SELECT
    T.Value1
   ,T.Value2
  FROM #Demo T
  WHERE T.Id = This.Id
  FOR XML PATH('BasicInfo'),ELEMENTS XSINIL,TYPE)
FROM  #Demo   AS This

DROP TABLE #Demo`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about SSIS, so I can't help you there. I'm quite sure the issue is actually related to SQL Server rather than XSLT, though.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

**XML**

```
<BasicInfo>
  <Foo>80</Foo>
  <Bar>
  </Bar>
</BasicInfo>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BasicInfo>
  <Foo>80</Foo>
  <Bar/>
</BasicInfo>
```

---

**Explanation:**

The `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` instruction will remove the whitespace-only text node contained by the `Bar` element, and the processor will automatically output an empty element as a self-closing tag.

Comment: I had tried a script similarly to this before, which is when I added the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` bit, but it has not worked (see comments on question, which were added after this answer).

Comment: If you're getting a different result, then either your input is different or the processor's behavior is different. The processor is not obligated to use self-closing tags, though most will. If your won't, there's no way to force it - at least not through the stylesheet.

Comment: hmm. That is unfortunate. If I were to use a different method to apply the XSLT Transform, might I be able to choose the processor or something to change behaviour - for instance using a script task in SSIS instead of the built-in XML task? In your opinion, do you think it is worthwhile experimenting, or probably just a dead end?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know what options you have in SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

The normal behaviour with `NULL` is to ommit the element completely...

If I get this right, you place `ELEMENTS XSINIL` to force the engine to introduce all elements even in case of `NULL`.

A hacky trick might be to remove the attributes like here:

```
CREATE TABLE #Demo ( Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL 
                    ,Value1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
                    ,Value2 VARCHAR(30) NULL ); 
INSERT #Demo(Value1,Value2) 
    VALUES('Bar',NULL); 


WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://tempuri.org/MySchema.xsd' AS xsd) 
SELECT This.Id 
     ,( SELECT T.Value1 
              ,T.Value2
        FROM    #Demo   T 
        WHERE   T.Id = This.Id 
        FOR XML PATH('BasicInfo'),ELEMENTS XSINIL,TYPE) AS TheXml
INTO #Demo2
FROM    #Demo   AS This;
UPDATE #Demo2 SET TheXml.modify('delete (//*/@*[local-name()="nil"])');

SELECT * FROM #Demo2 
GO
DROP TABLE #Demo
DROP TABLE #Demo2;
```

Comment: That certainly provides the correct output in SQL - I will give it a go tomorrow. It's a pity that it is not encapsulated in an XSLT, but a hacky trick is better than no trick!

Comment: Using modify in SQL Server does provide the correct solution, although if I subsequently use any stylesheets, they are all reinstated. I will use this and try to work my way around things. It seems a pity that there should be differing behaviours in this way without any choice to choose them.

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter The main question is: Why is this important? From your question I take, that you want to save storage place... At least with SQL-Server the XML **is not stored as the string you see**, but is stored as a hierarchy tree. No difference here... The *normal behaviour* is to ommit `NULL` value elements (even less bytes!). Just add a schema to tell a consumer which elements are to be expected? So again: Why?

Comment: The file size of the eventual .xml file that the SSIS Package saves is affected by the content of the .xml and as stated in the OP, removing the nodes does not seem an option. The reasons for this are not relevant to the question - I would do this if I were free to do so and may need to devote more time trying to get to that point. Sadly I find myself in a position where I believe it would be useful to have the question answered.

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter *it would be useful to have the question answered*: Well this question is answered by michael.hor257k: **there's no way to force it** (other than hacky tricks)... The internal *format* of an XML should not matter as long as it is valid. In your case I assume there's a reading tool or a schema contract which demands `NULL` values as empty nodes (rather than missing nodes). Even if you force it (like above), the next (XSLT-) step might destroy your effort...